# Laravel: return true if record exist else false

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a project in which any user can like someone else business. Now I want to check it with query that either the requested business is like by current user or not. I want to make laravel eloquent which need to show following output.

```
{
    "message": "Business found successfully",
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 7,
        "name": "Shimiring Car service",
        "location_name": "Gujranwali Schoole of Science and technolgoy",
        "lat": "52.124578",
        "long": "52.124578",
        "description": "This is a testing description",
        "bannar_img": "business/F8uVexNEm57A4DZ.png",
        "business_img": "business/MXKU7LDjOaBG9iF.png",
        "created_at": "2022-09-07T23:46:05.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-13T15:56:04.000000Z",
        "is_featured": 0,
        "featured_at": "2022-09-13 05:09:04",
        "category_id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "is_liked": false

    }
}
```

I am able to achieve it with two separate eloquent query but i want it to done in single query. below code is working fine but I want it to do in single eloquent ?

```
 $business = Business::where('id', $business_id)
            ->first();

            $business['is_favourite'] = FavouriteBusiness::where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->where('business_id', $business_id)
            ->first() == null ? false : true;
```

Here is my query that I am currently trying with for extracting the business, with like and unlike status, but its giving nothing ?

```
$business = Business::where('id', $business_id)
            ->whereHas('is_favourite', function($q) use($user_id) {
                return $q->where('user_id', $user_id)->exists() ? true : false;
            })
```

My Business model have this relation:

```
  public function is_favourite()
    {
        # code...
        return $this->hasOne(FavouriteBusiness::class);
    }
```

Here is my Favourite product migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favourite_businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->foreignId('business_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here is my Business Table migration:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->string('name', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('location_name', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('lat', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('long', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('description', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('bannar_img', 255)->default('');
            $table->string('business_img', 255)->default('');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain in brief as did not getting your question

Comment: If you are getting errors, then show us the errors

Comment: And its one question per question I am afraid

Comment: Can you please add your table structure?

Comment: hi; it might be helpful to try this method
Business::with('is_favorites')

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question and I think its much clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I fully understand the question but I have some inputs on the code provided.

Your database migrations doesn't seem to be quite correct.

[The Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) states that you have to add "constrained("some-table")" when using the foreignId method to actually associate the foreign key with another table.

So your migrations should be changed. Your favourite_businesses migration should for example look like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favourite_businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->foreignId('business_id')->constrained('businesses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The query using whereHas should only exist of the query inside, no need to make a conditional statement, and don't forget to use get() at the end to get a collection instead of the query builder:

```
$business = Business::where('id', $business_id)
            ->whereHas('is_favourite', function($q) use($user_id) {
                return $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
            })->get();
```

After the migration is setup correctly, this will return the business which has a favorite_business based on the user_id

Comment: thanks for you answer, let me make my question more clear to you. Rach user can create his business and other users can like or dislike that business. So I just want to fetch all businesses and add true if I like them and false if I don't like them.

Comment: That is what the query is doing. If a business have a "is_favourite" where "user_id" = user_id. Then you can check with isset($business) to either return true or false.